# Angular 9 Doesn't Navigate to Anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll, angular9

I have an angular application and I'm trying to link to specific locations on a page via anchors and navigating from code.  I have set up the router with the following `ExtraOptions`:

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
};
```

I am using the following code to navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], {fragment: 'tasks'}).then(success => {
  if (!success) {
    console.log('Error navigating to home');
  }
});
```

This does indeed put the anchor at the end of the url so it becomes `http.../home#tasks` so that seems correct.  However, instead of scrolling to the 'tasks' anchor which is near the top to scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page.  I also tried setting the `scrollPositionRestoration` property to both `top` and `disabled` and neither seemed to change anything.

I do have internal links on the home page that scroll to the anchors in question and those work as expected so I know the anchors are in the right place and everything.

What am I missing?  How do I get it to scroll to the anchor properly?  I also did Google this and found several things that have lead me to the code above but I haven't found anything else so as far as I can see this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use this feature yet but see this [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-scroller?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage1%2Fpage1.component.ts);

and I don't see your code and it's so hard to tell what is wrong. Maybe you have another item with tasks id or...?

But try this too I hope that it'll help you:

```
  constructor(private loc: Location, private router: Router, private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe((e: any) => {
  console.log(e);

  // this is fix for dynamic generated(loaded..?) content
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (e.position) {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
    } else if (e.anchor) {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
    } else {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
  });
});
}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!  So I'm not 100% sure I understand what this is doing though and why it works.  It seems like it is just subscribing to the event and then doing the same thing the event was doing... Obviously it's not but I'm not sure I understand why.  Anyway it works so thank you!  If you care to add more detailed explanation of what is happening here I would be interested (and would up vote it) but if not no worries.

Comment: if you give me a stackblitz link maybe i can give you a better answer but i think you just don't ask for scrolling when you add this routing to html btn or link it trigger the angular detect change automatically and do scrolling for you but you don't trigger detect change (read more for this topic) if you use this code it will manually scroll asyncrounusly after router change (extra: although async and observable trigger detect change) you can try it with sample code (1.comment the code 2.press #item15 3. add your code and set fragment item8 and you will see nothing happened)